# "Gained the academic title of professor"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, capitalization, collocation

I have a bit of a problem finding the right way to say/write the following:

> Gained the academic title of professor of xxx.

Is the choice of *gained* fine, or should I use some other verb that is used more frequently in this context? Maybe *obtain* or *earn*, or something else, is more proper?

Also, should it be "the academic title" at all, or rather a "degree"? I personally didn't use *degree* because I would use it when emphasizing a Baccalaureate as opposed to Master's degree, for example. In this case, it's just a matter of simply stating the fact that a certain title (degree?) is a result of studies.

Lastly, maybe *professor* should be capitalized?

I know, these questions must be awful and ridiculous, but it's been a long time since I even had to use my English in a serious situation. So I trust I'll get some help here.

Comment: Could you please specify where you would be using this? (i.e., bio, CV, resumé?) That might affect what would be the most appropriate answer.

Comment: A CV, yes. On that note, since I would use British English, is saying ''CV'' (all capital letters) better than ''resume'', as in saying: ''In addition: a CV/resume in English.''

Comment: http://jobsearch.about.com/cs/curriculumvitae/f/cvresume.htm

What are you making this for? Are you applying for an academic position or for a job? The former calls for a CV and the latter calls for a Resume.

Comment: No, I did use Resume, but was uncertain because of all of the U.S. television shows using ''resume, resume...'', so I thought it was more American than British.

Comment: Oh, to answer your question: no more academic degrees (positions) for me!Done with the university, of to the ''great wide world''...

Comment: So, call it a Resume.

Comment: If Jonathan Spirit's answer helped you, then please award him a magnificent green tick or just upvote his answer and wait to see if other helpful suggestions come through.

Comment: What is a ''magnificent green tick ''?

Comment: @user57153 Mari-Lou is referring to the green checkmark that appears when an answer is marked as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

I would say Earned, which is more commonly used with diplomas and degrees.

Question 2:

Not degree in this situation. Becoming a professor doesn't facilitate receiving a degree. It's most likely just "title" in this case.

Question 3:

Professor should only be capitalised if you put it before a name: "He is a professor" and "Professor James."

These are not stupid questions. These are very good questions that some people don't ask because they think people will look down on them for asking them. It's good that you are curious about things like these. The more you learn, the better.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, so very much. It is so rare that I stumble upon a nice, polite, let alone helpful answer on the Internet, actually asking these very things.

Comment: You are very welcome. There are many nice people on this website and I have yet to see a demeaning or downsizing answer, so bring your great grammar questions here instead!

Comment: And I'm much more reassured now as to which is the proper way to use in these examples. 

I did write: ''academic title'', but I actually got confused by the dictionary results for ''title''. I looked in http://www.thefreedictionary.com/academic, and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/academic, but they never mention ''title'', so I began to frighten that it should only be used with for example ''nobility titles''.

Comment: No, title is the best word in this situation. Academic is already implied by professor so is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am studying English/Business and Communication-Politics. My first thought was "achieved" .  It says, in my eyes, what verbs like accomplished, graduated, and distinguished express. You made your way and achieved a professional skill.
Its my humble opinion. I am a native German, and the translation of achieved into German hits exactly a polite expression of gaining, accomplishing, ect...
a academic level without giving to much stress on it.